# Neural Machine Translation from Latex to English without sufficient training data

Tags: neural-network, latex, training-data, supervised-learning, machine-translation

I'm trying to build a Neural Machine Translation model that translates Latex-code into English.
An example for this would be: "\frac{1^{n}}{12}" -> "One to the power of n divided by 12".
The problem is that I don't have nearly enough labeled training data to produce a good result.

Is there a way to train the model with s small data set or to artificially increase the amount of training data for this problem?

I have found solutions for machine translation without parallel data, that built a dictionary ["by aligning monolingual word embedding spaces in an unsupervised way"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.04087). These approaches seem to rely on the fact that human languages are very similar in nature. But Latex-code is very different than human languages and I don't think that's going to yield great results.